# FTP のエラー 504: 引数やパラメータが未実装 がわかりません

Tags: ftp

FileZillaを使ってFTP接続しようとすると以下のエラーコードが出ますが、どう改善したらいいのかわかりません。

```
    wwwftp.eonet.ne.jp のアドレスを解決中
状態:             59.190.154.17:21 に接続中...
状態:             接続を確立しました。ウェルカム メッセージを待っています...
レスポンス:  220 FTP Server ready.
コマンド:       AUTH TLS
レスポンス:  504 Command not implemented for that parameter
コマンド:       AUTH SSL
レスポンス:  504 Command not implemented for that parameter
エラー:        致命的なエラー: サーバーに接続できません
```

Comment: 暗号化をしなければ動くような気がします。

Answer (score 1):

接続時のオプションで「暗号化」の項目を確認してください。

従来からの "FTP" 接続では認証情報を平文でやり取りするので現在は非推奨となっています。
代わりに "FTP over TLS" が使われる事が多いですが、これは接続先サーバの設定に合わせる必要があります。

FileZilla で新規接続しようとした場合には「FTP over TLS」がデフォルトで選ばれているので、接続先に応じて「平文のFTPのみを使用する」を選択してみてください。

[image]